# Successfully deployed app on heroku but shows me Application Errror in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am building an app using ruby on rails following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. 
I tried to deploy the app on heroku and apparently I had no problems in doing so, but once I open the app on heroku it shows me an application error. I am pretty much clueless... this is the Log file:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (= 3.0.4) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.15.1) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Fetching git://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake 10.3.2
       Using i18n 0.6.11
       Using minitest 4.7.5
       Using thread_safe 0.3.4
       Using multi_json 1.10.1
       Using tzinfo 0.3.41
       Using builder 3.1.4
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using mime-types 1.25.1
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Using polyglot 0.3.5
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
       Using arel 4.0.2
       Using bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2
       Using sass 3.4.4
       Using will_paginate 3.0.4
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Using execjs 2.2.1
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using json 1.8.1
       Using pg 0.15.1
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Using faker 1.1.2
       Using activesupport 4.0.2
       Using treetop 1.4.15
       Using rack-test 0.6.2
       Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.9
       Using bootstrap-sass 2.3.2.0
       Using coffee-script 2.3.0
       Using rdoc 3.12.2
       Using uglifier 2.1.1
       Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Using sprockets 2.10.1
       Using actionpack 4.0.2
       Using activemodel 4.0.2
       Using jbuilder 1.0.2
       Using mail 2.5.4
       Using sdoc 0.3.20
       Using railties 4.0.2
       Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
       Using actionmailer 4.0.2
       Using activerecord 4.0.2
       Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Using jquery-rails 3.0.4
       Using sass-rails 4.0.1
       Using rails 4.0.2
       Using turbolinks 1.1.1
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (8.32s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (>= 0) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-rails (= 3.0.4) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.15.1) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
       Your Gemfile lists the gem rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) more than once.
       You should probably keep only one of them.
       While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally

###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 23.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v27
       http://guarded-shelf-9628.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

After comparing it with the logs from previous successful deploys, I found a slight difference. On this log it says `Default types for ruby -> console, rake, worker`  while in the other logs from succesful deploys it says `Default types for ruby -> console, rake, web, worker`  so a **web** maybe is missing there and can be causing the trouble... Do you think that could be the issue? If thats the problem... I don't know how to fix that! :) Would love to hear from someone who could help me with this!  Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is the Log that might provide info about the error:

```
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981295+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981299+00:00 app[web.1]: `config/application.rb` file and an
y `mass_assignment_sanitizer` options
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981302+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981294+00:00 app[web.1]: params or add `protected_attributes
` to your Gemfile to use the old one.
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981300+00:00 app[web.1]: from your `config/environments/*.rb
` files.
2014-09-19T22:58:43.981330+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252040+00:00 app[web.1]: A server is already running. Check
/app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252144+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252142+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:23779
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252140+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252145+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-09-19T22:58:44.252147+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-09-19T22:58:45.031535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-19T22:58:45.020850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-19T23:00:06.776445+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com
2014-09-19T23:00:09.905857+00:00 heroku[run.8558]: Awaiting client
2014-09-19T23:00:09.944483+00:00 heroku[run.8558]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-09-19T23:00:10.286566+00:00 heroku[run.8558]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-09-19T23:00:15.233196+00:00 heroku[run.8558]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-09-19T23:00:15.217870+00:00 heroku[run.8558]: Process exited with status 0
2014-09-19T23:09:00.021083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-09-19T23:09:06.045524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 52238`
2014-09-19T23:09:08.517868+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-ra
ils (>= 0) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.525341+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.525343+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.517884+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.517887+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.518722+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-r
ails (= 3.0.4) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.535911+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.535913+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.518726+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.518728+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.525337+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.
15.1) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:08.535904+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rails_12
factor (= 0.0.2) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:16.478210+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: config.whiny_n
ils option is deprecated and no longer works. (called from block in <top (requir
ed)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:6)
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602557+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602552+00:00 app[web.1]: config.eager_load is set to nil. Pl
ease update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602560+00:00 app[web.1]:   * development - set it to false
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602561+00:00 app[web.1]:   * test - set it to false (unless
you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602563+00:00 app[web.1]:   * production - set it to true
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602564+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:16.602588+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980362+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Model based ma
ss assignment security has been extracted
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980372+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980380+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/s
ecurity.html#mass-assignment for more information.
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980375+00:00 app[web.1]: `config/application.rb` file and an
y `mass_assignment_sanitizer` options
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980378+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980374+00:00 app[web.1]: To disable this message remove the
`whitelist_attributes` option from your
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980377+00:00 app[web.1]: from your `config/environments/*.rb
` files.
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980406+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980370+00:00 app[web.1]: params or add `protected_attributes
` to your Gemfile to use the old one.
2014-09-19T23:09:18.980368+00:00 app[web.1]: out of Rails into a gem. Please use
 the new recommended protection model for
2014-09-19T23:09:19.458144+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:52238
2014-09-19T23:09:19.458184+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-09-19T23:09:19.458145+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2014-09-19T23:09:19.458147+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-09-19T23:09:19.458138+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-09-19T23:09:19.450797+00:00 app[web.1]: A server is already running. Check
/app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
2014-09-19T23:09:20.395099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-19T23:09:20.407213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-19T23:09:20.407904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-09-19T23:09:24.294382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 11906`
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659179+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-ra
ils (>= 0) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659198+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659196+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659738+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem jquery-r
ails (= 3.0.4) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659743+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.659741+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664097+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664091+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (= 0.
15.1) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664325+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem rails_12
factor (= 0.0.2) more than once.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664099+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664328+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one o
f them.
2014-09-19T23:09:26.664330+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it co
uld cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2014-09-19T23:09:28.647892+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: config.whiny_n
ils option is deprecated and no longer works. (called from block in <top (requir
ed)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:6)
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717340+00:00 app[web.1]: config.eager_load is set to nil. Pl
ease update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717344+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717346+00:00 app[web.1]:   * development - set it to false
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717347+00:00 app[web.1]:   * test - set it to false (unless
you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717349+00:00 app[web.1]:   * production - set it to true
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717350+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:28.717352+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932824+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Model based ma
ss assignment security has been extracted
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932830+00:00 app[web.1]: out of Rails into a gem. Please use
 the new recommended protection model for
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932831+00:00 app[web.1]: params or add `protected_attributes
` to your Gemfile to use the old one.
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932833+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174451+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932835+00:00 app[web.1]: To disable this message remove the
`whitelist_attributes` option from your
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932838+00:00 app[web.1]: from your `config/environments/*.rb
` files.
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932836+00:00 app[web.1]: `config/application.rb` file and an
y `mass_assignment_sanitizer` options
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932842+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932839+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174417+00:00 app[web.1]: A server is already running. Check
/app/tmp/pids/server.pid.
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174453+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-09-19T23:09:29.932841+00:00 app[web.1]: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/s
ecurity.html#mass-assignment for more information.
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174447+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174454+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-09-19T23:09:30.174450+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:11906
2014-09-19T23:09:31.093052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-19T23:09:31.072183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-19T23:09:33.082176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-shelf-9628.herokuapp.com request_id=fae64
19e-d8ca-498f-ab94-936295266fe4 fwd="190.195.118.32" dyno= connect= service= sta
tus=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Have you run migrations? `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: @BroiSatse Yes I did, but still have the same problem :/

Comment: Run `heroku logs` and show the output. (Also, have you run heroku restart after migrations? Models are being cached in production)

Comment: 2014-09-19T23:09:31.072183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-19T23:09:33.082176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=guarded-shelf-9628.herokuapp.com request_id=fae64
19e-d8ca-498f-ab94-936295266fe4 fwd="190.195.118.32" dyno= connect= service= sta
tus=503 bytes=

Comment: I ran heroku restart but same issue... above is the part of the log that I think shows the error... but I am pretty new and can't decipher it

Comment: @santlib - We'll need some more of the logs. Could you paste it into your question, please?

Comment: yes! You can check it out now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: try running your application locally in production mode `rake assets:precompile; rails s -e production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone interested... after hours of pretty much trying EVERYTHING, I was finally able to solve it!

So the thing was that my **server.pid** file had something wrong... instead of a number, in my master branch it only had a line of text saying "sign-up" which looked pretty weird, so I went to a previous branch I was working on, copied the content of the server.pid file and pasted it into the one in the master branch, commited and pushed to heroku and now the app runs smoothly! :)

Thanks a lot to everyone who contributed!

Comment: where do you find this server.pid file?

Answer (score 0):

## Errors

There are two types of error with Heroku - the *platform* error and the *syntax (Rails)* error:

--

**Platform**

[image]

The first problem is the *platform* error

This is Heroku level, and basically means that your "system" (platform) does not operate correctly. It's either that you have a dependency missing / broken, or the configuration of the platform is incorrect.

In *most* cases, the reason this shows is because you've not referred to the correct database - preventing your app from even starting. I'll explain how to fix this below

--

**Syntax**

[image]

This a *Rails* problem - meaning that all your "platform" level technology will be working correctly. If you get one of these errors, it basically means you have some sort of problem with your Rails application itself (not just the platform it runs on)

Receiving this type of error basically means that you have to correct a problem with your code (not the platform). Although this can mean dependencies

---

**Fix**

From your error, it's evident you have a problem with Heroku, and not likely rails. To this end, I would recommend the following:

> 1. Check the database configuration for your app
> 2. Check if it's migrated correctly
> 3. Check if everything is updated & dependencies running

Firstly, and most importantly, you need to **make sure you have a "production" database assigned in Heroku***. Although you can use any db, you'll be best using Heroku's on-board [PGSQL setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) -- which if installed from the Heroku dashboard, should give your application the ability to run a production db

Secondly, you need to migrate to that database. You can do this by running `heroku run rake db:migrate` in your local development system - which will populate the database described above

Finally, you'll want to make sure Heroku has all the appropriate dependencies etc. This is done with the add-ons, and being completely honest, will not likely feature in your issue (its really rare)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My database configuration for my app apparently is fine. I am using PGSQL, and my database.yml files have postgresql set as adapter in all three environments. I migrated to my postgresql database in my local machine and checked the schemas in both dev and prod environments and they are there. I precompiled before migrating to heroku just in case, and after I pushed the code to Heroku I ran "heroku run rake db:migrate"... How do I make sure I havea "production" database assigned in heroku? I have also the heroku postgres::crimson add on